# getFragments method returns only 1 fragment when using replace transactions, used to return all

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

As of SDK 26.0.0-beta1 and above, making use of the `getFragments` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html#getFragments() method returns a list with only 1 fragment and the size of the list is also always 1 (so this excludes any possible null entries that might have been misleading me), when using `replace` method for fragment navigation.

Keep in mind I am using `getSupportFragmentManager`, not `getFragmentManager`

Prior to this SDK version all fragment transactions done with `replace` would be listed in the `getFragments` method. This means that if I replaced 10 fragments then the `getFragments` would return a list containing all of those 10 fragments.

However, from SDK 26.0.0-beta1 - specifically - and above (26.0.0-alpha1 and below does not have this problem) the method always returns a list of size 1 containing only the last fragment that was replaced.

To circumvent this problem I started using `add` and hiding whichever was the previously visible fragment, and so far this worked for what I wanted, which was to check which is the first fragment in the `getFragments` list whenever I needed as well as seeing if a certain instance of a fragment is already in that list.

Now a new problem arises when I try to use shared elements transitions, which only works with `replace` (as far as my google fu allowed me to find) meaning that if I want to use shared elements transitions I have to return to using `replace` fragments instead of `add`, but I will be back to the initial problem again.

So now I am stuck in this predicament and hoping anyone has a solution for this:

- Is there any way to fix this?
- Is the `getFragments` suppose to only return 1 fragment when we only use the `replace` method or is this behavior an undocumented bug that is yet to be fixed?
- Is it possible to make shared element transitions between fragments without using `replace`?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post and you've probably solved it by now, but it's the first thing I found whilst Googling the same problem so hopefully this helps someone (and probably myself when I search for the same problem in a few months' time).

If you call fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() you should get a count of all your fragments on the backstack. Assuming you assigned your fragments a tag when you added/replaced them and then added them to the backstack you can then get the tag of a fragment on the backstack and use fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag() to get its instance.

To set a tag during fragment add/replace:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, fragmentName)
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, fragmentName)
```

And to add it to the backstack:

```
transaction.addToBackStack(fragmentName);
```

And then to loop through your backstack to find a particular fragment:

```
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
for (int i = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName());
    // ...
}
```

I'm iterating through the fragments in reverse, so the last fragment I added will be returned first.